# Send Parameter DateTime in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem for sending parameters datetime type in javascript.
I have a function

```
function LoadHamuleFromDate(date) {
    alert(date);
    var day = date.toString().substr(0, 2);
    var month = date.toString().substr(2, 2);
    var year = date.toString().substr(4, 4);
    var d = day + "." + month + "." + year;
    alert(d);
}
```

When I send a date parameter to this function, my code crashed and I dont know why

```
document.getElementById("div_TarihButtonList").innerHTML += "<a   class='small button' 
' onclick='LoadHamuleFromDate(" + Number(result[i].tarih) + ")'>" + result[i].tarih + "</a></div>";
```

I can see results and have no problematic data, but when I click and send 10.10.2010
, I get this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`.
What can I do for this problem?

Comment: what is coming `result[i].tarih` to you?

Comment: did you try debug on chrome console ?

Comment: yes i tried and i got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. for example 10.10.2010

Comment: Where are the result[i].tarih coming from ? like @AshishKumar asked

Comment: result[i].tarih is my data from server like 10.10.2010

Comment: please review my updated answer, the Number() cast is your culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:

more than likely the culprit is your Number() cast you are using.

```
onclick='LoadHamuleFromDate(" + Number(result[i].tarih) + ")'
```

Note: When using Number(), if the parameter is a Date object, the Number() function returns the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970 UTC.

Also, if you're not passing it a date, but actualy the string "10.10.2014" or similar, it will throw a NaN error as that is not a number or a date.

Remove the number cast and try again:

```
document.getElementById("div_TarihButtonList").innerHTML += "<a   class='small button' 
' onclick='LoadHamuleFromDate(" + result[i].tarih + ")'>" + result[i].tarih + "</a></div>";
```

SIDE NOTE:

i made a fiddle out of your javascript only, and it runs without errors. It does however alert the wrong result because your subst calls are wrong.  **IF** your input is in the format DD.MM.YYYY, then it should look like this:

```
var day = date.toString().substr(0, 2);
var month = date.toString().substr(3, 2);
var year = date.toString().substr(6, 4);
```

As other posters have said, if you are getting the date format in multiple ways, your code needs to handle that as well.  I'm just addressing what you said your date format was.

http://jsfiddle.net/CyBQJ/

Comment: the problem is not substr. i can never send my date parameter to function.

Comment: when i get my result[i].tarih like 10102010 in alert i saw 295944. when i get result[i].tarih like 10.10.2010 i got Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error. i dont understand

Comment: Problem is not substr i cant send parameter date to function.

Comment: then something is wrong with the parameter you are sending.  More than  likely its the Number(x) cast you are doing. thats not for dates.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle both the cases: `10102014` & `10.10.2014`

Try this:

```
function LoadHamuleFromDate(date) {
    var d, m, y;

    d = date.toString().substr(0, 2); // day

    if(!isNaN(date)){ // 10102014       
        m = date.toString().substr(2, 2);
        y = date.toString().substr(4, 4);
    } else { // 10.10.2014
        m = date.toString().substr(3, 2);
        y = date.toString().substr(6, 4);
    }

    alert(day + "." + month + "." + year)
}
```

==== EDIT =====

I have a better solution:

```
function LoadHamuleFromDate(date) {
    var _date = date.toString().replace(/\./gi, ""), // conversion from 10.10.2014 to 10102014 format
        day = _date.toString().substr(0, 2),
        month = _date.toString().substr(2, 2),
        year = _date.toString().substr(4, 4);

    alert(date + " --> " + day + "." + month + "." + year);
    //return _date;
}
```

Comment: when i want to see my date parameter for alert on top function like

Comment: So, put one more alert before the existing one. Like alert (date)